# Using Boost Graph Library (BGL) with existing graph data structure

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have an existing graph, built from my own vertex and edge classes, as follows:

```
struct Graph;

struct OutPort {};

struct InPort { 
  OutPort* connectedOutput; 
};

struct Node { 
  Graph* graph;
  std::list<InPort> inputs;
  std::list<OutPort> outputs;
};

struct Graph {
  std::list<Node> nodes;
}
```

That is, the graph is composed of nodes, which have 0..* input and output ports. An input port be connected to to 0..1 output ports of any node (including its own).

I would like to apply the BGL algorithms to this graph, but cannot figure out how to do it while using either keeping my existing data structures above, or provide a suitable mapping between them and the BGL data structures.

I would be grateful for an introductory example.

Answer (score 0):

Making the example is a little bit involved. However, you need to model a graph concept of your choosing.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html

[image]

I find it hard to see from your model how edges are represented (ports could well be disconnected, or maybe `OutPort` refers back to a `Node` etc.). I sense you might want to model AdjacencyGraph. The required operations are listed on the linked page.

Comment: Thanks. my example is indeed bare-bone, but Ports are always owned by a single Node. OutPorts don't reference anything, and InPorts reference 0..1 OutPort.

Comment: So, how will you want to identify a vertex? I reckon by a single inport? In that case you basically have your own ad-hoc adjacency_list. Boost's generic one models VertexAndEdgeListGraph, MutablePropertyGraph, CopyConstructible, Assignable, and Serializable. You will probably have enough with a subset of those :)